# What is a matcap and where is it located in blender 2.8?

Tags: matcaps

What is a matcap and where is it located in blender 2.8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Matcap is a way of shading objects in the viewport.

It is located here, in the little dropdown box in the top right of the viewport.

[image: matcap]

Comment: Thanks. I tried googling it but everything just said "new matcaps" but didn't really have anything for what it is.

Comment: A matcap is basically a look-up table for the color at a specific normal direction in camera space. The sphere represents all the possible normal directions in the half sphere with positive z coordinates under orthographic projection. The image coordinate system is at the top left corner. The normal coordinate system is centered in the middle of the sphere. This means for each normal in the normal pass we can look up the color in the matcap by shifting and normalizing the coordinates.

Comment: I don't get those options when clicking the drop down. Missing the options under Lighting.

Comment: If you don't see those options in the drop down, it's likely because you are not in solid shading. Matcaps are not available in material preview or rendered shading.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Viewport Shading* dropdown in the top right corner, only available in *Solid* shading mode.